# How do I determine the relationship between initial and final volume in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Some total volume contains two compartments separated by a wall that allows for mechanical and thermal interaction, each compartment having a different amount of an ideal gas. For the initial conditions: $V_{A,i}=2V_{B,i}$ , $P_{A,i}=3P_{B,i}$ and $T_{B,i}=T_{A,i}=T_i$. The sytem evolves into equilibrium. It's clear that this means that $T_{A,f}=T_{B,f}=T_i$ and $P_{A,f}=P_{B,f}$.

Using the facts above, it's easy to determine that $n_A=6n_B$ is simple, as well as determining that $V_{A,f}=6V_{B,f}$. However I can't seem to find a relationship between the initial volumes and the final volumes. The process is not adiabatic as if it were, the final temperatures would be different. Therefore I can't apply the Laplace-Poisson relationship. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the total compartment rigid and insulated?

Comment: @BobD Yes, the total space has those conditions.

Comment: So essentially you have a rigid insulated chamber with a movable thermally conductive barrier (e.g piston)

Comment: @BobD Yeah, though my problem is mostly algebraic and not conceptual. I can't seem to find an equation relating the two parameters. The solutions imply that, for chamber B (which is originally smaller), it should be $V_{B,f}=3/7 V_{B,i}$.

Comment: I'm confused, you just stated a relationship between the final volumes. The total volume $V_t$ is constant, so $V_{a,i}=\frac{2}{3}V_t$ and $V_{b,i}=\frac{1}{3}V_t$. The final volumes are $V_{a,f}=\frac{6}{7} V_t$ and $V_{b,f}=\frac{1}{7}V_t$. Therefore $V_{a,f}=\frac{9}{7}V_{a,i}$ and $V_{b,f}=\frac{3}{7}V_{b,i}$.

Comment: The final temperature can be determined from the condition that the change in internal energy of the combined system is zero.